# igraph Error could not find function "hist"

Tags: r, igraph

I am using RStudio Version 0.98.484 and R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing" on a Mac OSX 10.6.8.

here is an example of a code:

```
a  <- "a"
b  <- "b"
c  <- "c"
d  <- "d"
e  <- "e"
f  <- "f"

model1 <- ug(~a:b, ~a:c:d,~b:c,~a:c:d:f,~d:e:f,~b:f)
model1 <- as(model1, "igraph")
```

applying the functions:

```
cluster.distribution() #or
degree.distribution()
```

returns the error:

```
Error in cluster.distribution() : could not find function "hist"
Error in degree.distribution() : could not find function "hist"
```

Now i found this:

https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/257 with the following:
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/0567c2694a99686bbd1855299822ad52dcd5989a
slution.

But the problem seems to be different, since it is the hist() function that is not working under my 3.0.2 R version and not the "$intensities".

I downloaded the latest version of the igraph package from here:
https://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/detail?name=igraph_nightly_0.7-f8164af-20131004.tar.gz&can=2&q=

however when I try to install it in the Terminal using:
R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/igraph_0.7.tar.gz

the following error message comes up:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 144: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 145: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 259: make: command not found
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/B-/B-vij4PvG1K9q1Uv2RID9k+++TI/-Tmp-/RtmpU3N8GA/R.INSTALL3a66344bc5d4/igraph':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/igraph’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/igraph’
```

Comment: In regard to the compiling problem, make sure you have XCode and the developer tools installed.

Comment: can you be more sprecific: where can I check what I need, and what do I need?

Comment: @VincentGrunert Install Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ You'll need to register as a developer (free of charge).

Comment: Please make your code reproducible, I get `Error: could not find function "ug"`

Comment: "ug" is from the gRbase package to create an undirected graph. However for some reason it seems that restarting RStudio did the trick. Although i have no idea why.