# R iGraph: why "could not find function graph_from_literal"?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) on Ubuntu 14.04, igraph_0.7.1.
For some reason, I can't use the function 'graph_from_literal':

```
library(igraph)

gg1 <- graph.empty()
gg2 <- graph( c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6), directed=FALSE )
gg3 <- graph.ring(10)

g<-graph_from_literal( a-+b )
```

If I run that, I get the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "graph_from_literal"
```

Why is that? Is it because this particular function is not in the version 0.7.1? That function is not mentioned in the [new release 1.1.0](http://igraph.org/2015/06/24/igraph-1.0.0-r.html), though.
As far as I understand, it seems a more restricted issue than in missing general R functions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251097/igraph-error-could-not-find-function-hist).

Comment: I cannot replicate this on r3.3.0,, igraph v1.0.1, on ubuntu 14.04. Try upgrading R , and igraph version

Comment: actually, you can try `graph.formula`, which i think was the old name

Comment: Brilliant, 'graph.formula' works. So it must be a version issue. Thanks!